# Why do my desktop gadgets move from their previous positions when I exit NFS: Most Wanted?

Tags: windows-xp, need-for-speed-most-wanted-2005

Here is a problem I'm having ... I'm using Windows XP, and every time I play NFS: Most Wanted, when I close the game, my gadgets have moved from where I had them positioned. I'm using Vista_Rainbar for using gadgets on Windows XP.

This also happens after playing some other games, but I can't remember which ones at the moment.

So how can I fix this problem?

Comment: I'm guessing this is a resolution problem. So, what kind of resolution are you using for the game, and your desktop?

Comment: Move it back? :P

Comment: @mordi2k My display resolution is 1280*800px and in game there are only 2 resolution options are available first is 600* something and second is 800*600px.

Comment: @w69rdy nice joke buddy, every time time I do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is caused by a long-running bug in the Windows code. The gadgets do not auto-adjust their position after a resolution is changed to a bigger one.

Basically, when you are running a game with smaller resolution than your desktop, the desktop will automatically change the resolution to match the game's resolution, adjusting the gadgets to fit that resolution. When the resolution changes back, it is incapable of adjusting them back to the positions they were in.

There is currently no official fix for this, but there are a few workarounds you could try to use.

1. You could try exiting Vista_Rainbar before starting the game, and then start it after the game has shut down.
2. Running the game in window mode should also fix this problem.

Comment: How I can run the game in windows mode?

Comment: @avrik http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3t-XEgYgsLg